# Why "Class::method" and not just "method" when using menu_selector?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I have a class like this:

```
class A
{
    public:
         A();
         ~A();

         bool init(); 
    private:

         void LeftCallback(CCObject* sender);     
}
```

In my init method I try to create a menu_selector using:

```
menu_selector(LeftCallback);
```

The problem is that this does not work. I must provide the class scope to make it work this way:

```
menu_selector(A::LeftCallback);
```

Why am I forced to add the class scope in this situation instead of just using the method name?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it is a member function, how could it be found without the name of the class it belongs to?

Comment: Why not take it from current caller scope? I could be messed... but I think it is sensibble. Isn't it? I mean, I'm building the selector in a method that belongs to a class where the LeftCallback method belongs too.

Comment: In that case, you should clarify your question.

Comment: I hope my question is clearer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, because the language requires you to.

I'm not exactly sure why this was decided, but it does help avoid ambiguity between function and method pointers, even to humans reading your code.

Comment: Thanks, this is enough for me. Last time I used C++ was 2 years ago and have forgot this little things. Thanks for the information. Anyway visual studio spits a really cryptic error does has nothing to do with the real problem. '&' illegal operation on bound member function expression. For me this is not a good error explanation.

Comment: The reason is simply that "LeftCallback" could be either a class instance method OR a C function declared in the same file. To avoid this ambiguity the class name must be prefixed. A::LeftCallback refers to class A's LeftCallback method, whereas LeftCallback would refer to a C function named LeftCallback.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Really this is no more ambiguous than directly calling `LeftCallback(...)`, which resolves to calling the method, but I guess it does make the code a bit more explicit.